# Como passar ID via JavaScript para uma View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo uso Views do tipo *modal*.

Uso esse código para exibir o *modal*:

```
<button class="btn btn-default details" data-id="@clientes.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button>

$(".delete").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#modal").load("Excluir?id=" + id, function () {
        $(".modal").modal();
    })
});
```

Vemos que a minha *Modal* uso um ***"data-id"*** para passar o valor do ID, meu problema é o seguinte, preciso fazer algo parecido porém não usarei um *modal* e sim uma *View* normal, como seria meu *javascript* para isso?

Comment: Eu poderia usar um `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Cadastro", "Cliente")'"` mas não sei como adicionar um parâmetro nesse link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nem precisaria usar JavaScript. Um link normal já resolve tudo.

```
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Cadastro", "Cliente", new { id })'"
```

Comment: Foi algo muito simples, mas que me ajudou muito.
Obrigado mais uma vez por sua colaboração.